# 'Service Timeout' for OpenCPU webhook on Github

Tags: r, timeout, webhooks, opencpu

I've created a simple package in R and hosted it on Github. I want to create an API using OpenCPU own cloud servers.

The procedure is supposed to be simple: just add `http://cloud.opencpu.org/ocpu/webhook` as a webhook on Github.

When I do this, here's the message I'm getting:
`We couldn’t deliver this payload: Service Timeout`

What should I do? The package imports `markovchain`. Could this be somehow related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the package takes more than 30 seconds to build, Github will say there was a timeout. However it might still have been deployed. Did you not receive an email notification?

The [opencpu-ci](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/opencpu-ci) mailing list gets cc'd for every notification email. As you can see your package has been deployed 7 times in the past hour.

You can also just check `https://<yourname>.ocpu.io/` to check if it is there

Comment: Thank you. I haven't received any email for some reason (even checked spam).

Comment: Do you have an email address configured for this Github account ?

Comment: I do.. Anyway. Thanks again.